# Rails in which folder should ruby classes go into?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Rails in which folder should ruby classes go into?

I am reading [this guide](http://blog.leetsoft.com/2008/2/17/delayed-job-dj) and I am wondering in which folder the NewsletterJob class should be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put them in the **lib** folder. Or maybe add a folder under app, like **jobs** and you should get it loaded automatically in your environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the **lib** folder in rails 3, you need to add that to the load path, as rails 3 removed it by default:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```