# Best folder to place stand-alone modules and classes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Which is the best folder to place files that have methods which are not particularly M/V/C. These methods are called at places or in backend process from within the App. Where do I store them? Lib/Scripts/somewhere-else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails in which folder should ruby classes go into?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677063/rails-in-which-folder-should-ruby-classes-go-into)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually such modules are placed in the `lib`/ folder and since in Rails 3 modules and classes in  the `lib` folder aren't loaded automatically you should add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `application.rb` to make those classes and modules autoloadable.

Comment: If you are using `config.threadsafe!`, you will need to explicitly `require 'my_lib_file'` somewhere in your code. (Because of possible race conditions, even autoloading from config.autoload_paths is disabled).